# How to pass out ContentScript data out to a module-global variable in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, firefox, firefox-addon, firefox-addon-sdk, content-script

I been working on a firefox extension project and now I'm stuck on this,

```
var abc = 123;

var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  contentScript:  'var newabc = 456;',
});
```

where abc is a global variable and newabc is a variable within the contentScript.

How do I make abc = newabc ?

Thanks!!

Comment: Don't have experience using FF extensions, but have you tried changing `contentScript` to be `'var newabc = 456; abc = newabc;'`?  Probably a dumb suggestion, I'm just not familiar with FF extension scoping.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the Addon-SDK v1.0b3's [PageMod API](https://jetpack.mozillalabs.com/sdk/1.0b3/docs/packages/addon-kit/docs/page-mod.html):

```
var abc = 123;

var pageMod = require("page-mod");
pageMod.PageMod({
  include: "*",
  contentScriptWhen: 'ready',
  contentScript:  'var newabc = 456;postMessage(newabc);',
  onAttach: function onAttach(worker) {
    worker.on('message', function(newabc) {
      abc = newabc;
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: Hi thanks,I was new to SO, didn't know much about how it works at the time. Answer has been marked.